# sudo minikube returns "command not found"

Tags: minikube

I need to run minikube as sudo on Centos 7.5. 
Minikube is in /usr/local/bin

For the user echo $PATH is:

```
/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
```

For root echo $PATH is:

```
/usr/local/bin/:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

I even added the following to visudo

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Still

```
udo minikube start --cpus 4 --memory 24000 --disk-size=50g --kubernetes-version=v1.7.4 --vm-driver=none
```

returns sudo: minikube: command not found

What is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately questions like these are off-topic for Stackoveflow, and should be asked here: https://superuser.com. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the location of where the Minikube executable is for the root user to find it. I copied the executable to where root normally looks for files. Example: `sudo cp /usr/local/bin/Minikube /usr/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Running `brew link minikube` solved it for me. You have to create the symlink after installing minikube.